# how to edit the style of the el-breadcrumb in elementUI

Tags: css, vue.js, web-frontend

I'm trying to set the font-size of the `el-breadcrumb-item`, and I look up the style of this tag by the debugger tool of chrome; I found that
[image]

it shows that the font-size of `el-breadcrumb-item` is inherited from `el-breadcrumb`, so I try to set the font-size of `el-breadcrumb` and code like

```
<template>
  <el-breadcrumb separator="/">
    <el-breadcrumb-item :to="{ path: '/' }">HOME</el-breadcrumb-item>
    <el-breadcrumb-item>rankingList</el-breadcrumb-item>
  </el-breadcrumb>
</template>


<style scoped>
  .el-breadcrumb {
    font-size: 5em;
  }
</style>
```

but it fails, the font-size of the `el-breadcrumb-item` didn't change at all
it appears like that
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should change it in the element-ui default .css file.
Its priority is higher than your css,so it covers your change.

Answer (score 0):

take off scoped, your style overrides the default element style.